# React alias - module not found / javascript webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, alias

I'm trying to set up an alias in my app built with create-react-app .
I don't use typescript . The IDE (WebStorm) sees my alias paths. Shows the contents of a folder. But when I refresh the page, I get the error:
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@HomePage/HomePage' in 'C:\Users\ASUS\WebstormProjects\spnew\client\src'
I'm going to add the HomePage component which is in the HomePage folder.

My way:

```
1) I made an eject
2) Created a 'jsconfig.json' file in the root directory with react

    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        paths: {
          "@HomePage/*": ["./src/pages/HomePage/*"]
        }
      },
      "exclude": ["node_modules"]
    }

p.s. tried without @, tried to remove './'
p.s.s. after adding this file, the IDE reacts to:
import {...} from "@HomePage/"; tells you what files are in this folder.

3) The auto-generated webpack.config.js file has very few features.
On the Internet they write what needs to be done like this:

modules.exports = {
 resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    alias: {
      Components: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/components/'),
    }
  },
  ...
  resolve: {
    ...
  }
}

I already have over 700 lines in this file!
But the structure is the same. I found module.exports which has nested resollve which has nested alias. And added a line with the path.
It looks like this:

alias: {
        HomePage: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/pages/HomePage"),
        // Support React Native Web
        // https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/08/a-glimpse-into-the-future-with-react-native-for-web/
        'react-native': 'react-native-web',
        // Allows for better profiling with ReactDevTools
        ...(isEnvProductionProfile && {
          'react-dom$': 'react-dom/profiling',
          'scheduler/tracing': 'scheduler/tracing-profiling',
        }),
        ...(modules.webpackAliases || {}),
      }
p.s. I tried to write the path './' '../' and without it.
```

When importing, I get the same error!
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./src/routes.js 9:0-46

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@HomePage/HomePage' in 'C:\Users\ASUS\WebstormProjects\spnew\client\src'

Comment: If project not compiled, than you have problems with Webpack. Please notice, if write aliases with @ symbol, you should write imports with it in config too. Now you not. Try edit a key in `alias` object:

alias: {
        "@HomePage": path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/pages/HomePage"), 
}

Comment: any solutions for this ? I am facing the same issue